# detect zooming in and out on pdf.js

Tags: events, addeventlistener, zooming, pdf.js

I want to detect when a user is zooming in or out on a document that is opened with the pdf.js library on an iframe.  I'm pretty much looking for the term of "whatGoesHere" on the code below.  The equivalent of 'pagechange' or 'pagesloaded' only for zooming.

```
innerDoc.addEventListener('whatGoesHere', function(e) 
    {console.log("zoom changed!");});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that 'pagerendered' does trigger after every zoom, but it also triggers on page moves.  If there's an event strictly for zooming that'd be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 events for zooming:

```
zoomIn
zoomOut
zoomReset
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the pdf.js viewer, you can bind to the `scalechanged` event:

```
document.addEventListener('webviewerloaded', function () {
    console.log('web viewer loaded');

    // Wait for the PDFViewerApplication to initialize
    PDFViewerApplication.initializedPromise.then(function () {
        PDFViewerApplication.eventBus.on('scalechanged', function(e) {
           console.log("Do stuff here.");
        });
    )};
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/ffbfd680ec418c05afdcafb6b3e6e962f978f8b0/web/app.js#L1884